# Importing external npm module in Angular2

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I would like to import file-system npm library to my Angular 2 project and strictly followed these steps:
https://medium.com/@s_eschweiler/using-external-libraries-with-angular-2-87e06db8e5d1#.1dx1fkiew

Now it's done I have the following basically error and really don't know how am I suppose to import simple npm module to Angular 2 project...

> src/app/app.component.ts(2,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'file-system'

Here's my app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as fs from 'file-system';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: 'app/folio.html'
})
export class AppComponent  { 
  name = 'Angular'; 
  src = './app/img/';
  dir = fs.readdirSync(src);
}
```

I tried something related with typings :

> typings install file-system

but the module isn't find by typings to be installed.

Does anyone have a solution or know a good tutorial to include any npm modules in Angular 2 project ?

Comment: When hovering over 'file-system' in your import statement does it show you the path to the npm module?

Comment: Did the `npm install` work without errors (do you have a folder *node_modules/file-system/* with all files in it)? Did `tsd install` succeed?

Comment: You're likely going to have problems using any `fs` related modules in angular.

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg Yes for npm install, tsd install just tells me there's nothing.

Comment: @J.AdamConnor It tells me this: [ts] Could not find a declaration file for module 'file-system'. '[...]/quickstart/node_modules/file-system/file-system.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Though I have the file in the right place and did the right things in systemjs.config.js.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install @types/file-system --save`

Typings is deprecated. You should install straight from NPM.

Comment: Can you be more specific. What exactly is the error.

Comment: "npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "@types/file-system" "--sa" this is hte first one among others that I can"t copied